# как взять из массива объектов только некоторые значения?

Tags: javascript, массивы, сортировка, объекты, фильтрация

```
arrayObj = [
  {
    name: 'john',
    age: 23,
    image: [...]
  },
  {
    name: 'alex',
    age: 25,
    image: [...]
  }
]
```

как из этого получить массив объектов только с name?

```
result = [
  {
    name: 'john'
  },
  {
    name: 'alex'
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения Вашей задачи используйте функцию **map** для массива, например так

```js
arrayObj = [
  {
    name: 'john',
    age: 23,
    image: []
  },
  {
    name: 'alex',
    age: 25,
    image: []
  }
];


result = arrayObj.map((item) => ({ name: item.name }));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы получить конкретное значение из массива, вам нужно использовать индекс этого значения `arrayObj[0]['name']`. А чтобы получить все значения с этим индексом, вам нужно использовать цикл `while, for или foreach`.

```js
const arrayObj = [
    {
      name: 'john',
      age: 23,
      image: '[...]'
    },
    {
      name: 'alex',
      age: 25,
      image: '[...]'
    }
]

let x = 0

arrayObj.forEach(obj => {
    console.log(obj['name']);
})

for(let i = 0; i < arrayObj.length; i++){
    console.log(arrayObj[i]['name']);
}
while (x < arrayObj.length){
    console.log(arrayObj[x]['name']);
    x++
}
```